# Sorting arrays based on frequency in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a nested array of numbers, arranged like this:

```
ids = [[5,8,10],[8,7,25],[15,30,32],[10,8,7]]
```

I only need a single array with all of the keys inside, without repeating, so I used this:

```
ids = ids.flatten.uniq
```

That produces this:

```
ids = [5,8,10,7,25,15,30,32]
```

Since I used `.uniq`, it eliminates the duplicate values. However, I'd like to order the values based on how often they appear in the sub-arrays, rather than whichever order they happen to be in -- so something like this:

```
ids = [8,10,7,5,25,15,30,32]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do:

```
ids.flatten.group_by {|i| i}.sort_by {|_, a| -a.count}.map &:first
```

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Try running the command above step by step to see what is going on. Is there any particular element you are not sure about?

Comment: i tried it but it says there's a syntax error in there some where and since i'm new to rails i don't get the code very much and for the life of me i cant see the error bro

Comment: @BroiSatse I know what's going on, but if you just provide code then when someone has a similar but not identical problem, and _doesn't_ get it, this whole answer is useless. If you explain yourself, others can use it as well.

Comment: @fredo - How does the line with this code look like in your code? :) You might need to do `map(&:first)` in some cases.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Even though I would agree in general, this is pretty extremely simple task. If anyone is not sure what this code does, there are more then enough resources in the internet to check what given method does and it is not the purpose of this site to create basic ruby documentation.

Comment: i agree with @BroiSatse here. although one-liners are impressive, for obvious beginners like the OP, answers like mine are better suited. :-)

Comment: @Humza - Also, your answer has `O(n^2)` complexity while all the other answers are `O(n)`. :P

Comment: @BroiSatse i know! n00b answer for n00b question :P seriously though, the multi-lines pay to help explain code to newbies

Comment: yes! @Humza yours worked as well! but i can't mark both as correct.... anyway THANK YOU (both).... and yeah after reading your answer i kind of got the code it's just that rails has like a billion methods.... i'm trying to learn them step by step :p

Answer (score 3):

```
ids_flatten = [[5,8,10],[8,7,25],[15,30,32],[10,8,7]].flatten
ids_hist = ids_flatten.group_by{ |v| v }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }
soreted_ids_hist = ids_hist.sort_by{|x| -x[1]}

soreted_ids_hist.map(&:first)
 => [8, 7, 10, 25, 5, 15, 30, 32]
```

Answer (score 3):

Slow but clearly understandable (hopefully) to people new to Ruby:

```
flattened_ids = ids.flatten
unique_ids = flattened_ids.uniq
sorted_ids = unique_ids.sort_by { |e| -flattened_ids.count(e) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but:

```
ids.flatten.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |id, count| count[id] += 1 }.sort_by { |a| -a[1] }.map(&:first)
```